# Conversion de Datetime a string dentro de un objeto viewModel cuando se consulta a sql server

Tags: .net

tengo una exepcion cuando intento covertir una fecha que traigo de sql server a tipo string dentro de un objeto viewModel.

Dice lo siguente: System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' del método, y este método no se puede convertir en una expresión de almacenamiento.'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta antes de que llames el `.ToList()` de tu query todo ese codigo se intentara trasladar a sentencia SQL, para lo cual algunas funciones como la que tienes en la excepcion no podran ser traducidas a SQL, hasta aqui tienes dos opciones:

1. A tu query puedes adicionarle `.Tolist()` despues del `Where`. Con esto tendrías los objetos en memoria y el `.Select` podra aplicar el formato que le estas indicando sin problemas.
   Cabe resaltar que en `ToList()`, solo estaría trayendo las entidades de `ActividadesUser` y como en el `select` necesitas datos de `Usuario` y `Actividades`, es necesario que adiciones `.Include(`para incluir las relaciones de las entidades Hijas. Tu query quedaría asi por ejemplo:

> ```
> db.ActividadesUser
> .Include(x => x.User)
> .Include(x => x.Actividades)
> .Where(x => x.UserId == usuario)
> .ToList()
> .Select(x => new ActividadesViewModel
> {
> UsuarioId = x.User.Email,
> Actividad = x.Actividades.Actividad,
> Descripcion = x.Actividades.Descripcion,
> Fecha = string.Format("{0:ddd (MMMM yyyy)}", x.Actividades.Fecha)
> }).ToList()
> ```

2. No aplicarle el formato en el `.Select(` , trabajar con el tipo `datetime` en vez de `string` y darle formato que requieras en tu vista.

Saludos, espero te sirva

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio